# How does this dayOfTheYear function work?

Tags: javascript, date

Found this function online and it is exactly what I need, but if someone could breakdown how it works it would be much appreciated. Why is there no error when date isn't defined? What are the two 0 arguments that are passed? Also the division at the end ... those are dividing the result by milliseconds / minutes / hours?

```
function dayOfTheYear(date) {
  return Math.floor((date - new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 0)) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
}
```

Example:

```js
function dayOfTheYear(date) {
  return Math.floor((date - new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 0)) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
}

console.log(dayOfTheYear());
```

Comment: Please, you clearly see that without using `date` it **does not obviously work**. Edit your question to add more details of your use-case.

Comment: The two zeros are the month and day, which creates a Date object representing Jan 1, midnight. Subtracting that from the passed `date` gives the milliseconds since the current year has started, and dividing it by the milliseconds per day gives the day of year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs minor corrections and it provides the result you want.

```js
/* another way extending Date */
class myDate extends Date {
  constructor(date) {
    super(date);
  }
  dayOfTheYear() {      
  let dte = this;
  let year = dte.getFullYear();
  return Math.floor((dte - new Date(year, 0, 0)) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);  
}
}

function dayOfTheYear(date) {      
  let dte = new Date(date);
  let year = dte.getFullYear();
  /* 
  this part is all the work, (dte - new Date(year, 0, 0)) is actually
  current date - first day of the year 0 hour, 0 minute, 0second, 0 millisecond
  and return a timestamp in milliseconds, 
  the rest of the divisions are needed to turn milliseconds to days 
  */ 
  return Math.floor((dte - new Date(year, 0, 0)) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);  
}
let dt = new myDate('2020-09-16');
console.log('Child class output day of the year 2020-09-16: '+dt.dayOfTheYear());
console.log('Child class output of full year inherited from parent class: '+dt.getFullYear());
console.log('Function output day of the year 2020-09-16: '+dayOfTheYear('2020-09-16'));
console.log('Function output day of the year 2020-01-11: '+dayOfTheYear('2020-01-11'));
console.log('Function output day of the year 2020-01-01: '+dayOfTheYear('2020-01-01'));
console.log('Function output day of the year 2020-12-31: '+dayOfTheYear('2020-12-31'));
console.log('Function output day of the year 2020-03-16: '+dayOfTheYear('2020-03-16'));
```